# Facebook SDK iPhone, friends list

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, cocoa-touch, sdk

I have one question.
I want to share photos from my application via facebook. 
There is no problem to share it on my wall, but is there any possibility to share it on friend's wall ? 
Something like click  share button, log in, choose friends and share it on their wall ?
I have been searching application in appstore which can do that, but i found nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can post to a user's friend's feed using the Graph API, assuming the user granted you the relevant (publish_stream) permissions.

```
POST /[friend]/feed

message=hello&picture=http://...
```

I should stress strongly that users consider this very spammy behavior for apps, and it is not generally recommended.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/